# ReactJS - Passing prop value to component before final ReactDOM.render()

Tags: reactjs, properties, components

I want to pass a value to a component this way, but when I try to `console log this.props.vouch` it returns an undefined value. 
I know it will work if I put:

```
<Something onClick={this.log} vouch=this.props.vouch />
```

and

```
ReactDOM.render(<List vouch="value 1"/>, document.getElementById('react-app'))
```

But I will want to use different vouch value later in the code and be able to reuse Something component.

```
var Something = React.createClass({
 propTypes:{
    vouch: React.PropTypes.string,
},
    render: function() {
        return (
        <div>
            <h1 onClick={this.props.onClick} vouch={this.props.vouch}>Click!</h1>
        </div>
        );
    }
});
var List = React.createClass({

    log: function() {
        console.log(this.props.vouch);
    },
    render: function  () {
        return (
            <Something onClick={this.log} vouch="value 1" />
            <Something onClick={this.log} vouch="value 2" />
            );
    }
});
ReactDOM.render(<List />, document.getElementById('react-app'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set `this.props` from child component, but you can pass data using `data attributes`, like this

```
<h1 onClick={this.props.onClick} data-vouch={this.props.vouch}>Click!</h1>

...

log: function (e) {
    console.log(e.target.dataset.vouch);
},
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/24176/)

or using `.bind`, like this

```
<h1 onClick={this.props.onClick.bind(null, this.props.vouch)}>Click!</h1>

...

log: function (vouch) {
  console.log(vouch);
},
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/24177/)

or call callback in child component and pass props, like this

```
handleClick: function () {
  this.props.onClick(this.props.vouch)
},

render: function() {
  return (<div>
    <h1 onClick={this.handleClick}>Click!</h1>
  </div>)
}

...

log: function (vouch) {
  console.log(vouch);
},
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/24179/)

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing `this.props.vouch` to `List`, so your log will return undefined.

```
var Something = React.createClass({
    propTypes:{
        vouch: React.PropTypes.string,
    },
    onClick: function() {
        this.props.onClick( this.props.vouch )
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1 onClick={this.onClick.bind( this )} vouch={this.props.vouch}>Click!</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var List = React.createClass({

    log: function( vouch ) {
        console.log( vouch );
    },
    render: function  () {
        return this.props.vouch.map( vouch => <Something onClick={ log } vouch = { vouch } /> )
    }
});
var vouch = [
  {
    value: 'foo'
  },
  {
    value: 'bar'
  }
]
ReactDOM.render(<List vouch={ vouch } />, document.getElementById('react-app'));
```

The actual problem of your log not working could also be solved by passing `List.log` to `Something` (which you do already) and then invoking it in the context of `Something` by using `<h1 onClick={ this.props.onClick.call( this )` and having `log` `console.log( this.props.vouch )` but this solution would be nasty from a maintainability standpoint.

It is important to understand the parent->child relationship between components that you are creating. At any point you can grab your `vouch` data and inject it but by injecting it at the `List` component you keep all children pure i.e. when you render you are passing the state of the system, you arent attempting to grab state or worse, mutate, state during the life-cycle of a render.

Comment: The code does not work, but I see what you mean, I dont want vouch value to be predefined because it will vary too much later in the code. Is it not possible to give it string value in the List component?

Comment: if you want, its just an example or the `vouch` data structure, you'll have to change for your needs, you can pass whatever you like. Your problem arises because you're not passing properties correctly. I just borked the syntax, the philosophy is the same, the code should now run so you can examine the flow of properties.